# how to check if the image field is empty or have uploaded image?

Tags: theming, media

```
<?php
  $nid = arg(1);
  $path = arg(0);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if(isset($nid) && is_numeric($nid) && isset($path) && $path == 'node' && isset($node) && $node->type == 'page') {
    $theme_img = file_create_url($node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri']); //origional image path
    if($theme_img) {
        //image having style
        print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'page_theme'));
    }
   }
?>
```

I've loaded the above code in page.tpl.php. It is to load the uploaded styled image from individual pages. 
I am getting error in line no. 6 ($theme_img), for pages which have empty image field. It is working fine in pages which have image uploaded. How to know if this field is empty or have image uploaded.

Comment: you should check for empty image field like this: `!empty($node->field_page_cover_image)`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {

  // Set default language if not set
  $node->language = isset($node->language) ? $node->language : LANGUAGE_NONE;

  if ($node->type == 'page' && isset($node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'])) {
    print theme('image_style', 
            array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 
                  'style_name' => 'page_theme'));
  }

}
```

Odd you're printing out the image though, must be in a tpl file. I'd suggest moving the code logic to a hook_preprocess_node and setting a template variable instead.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node($variables){

  $node =& $variables['node']; // by reference
  // Set default language if not set
  $node->language = isset($node->language) ? $node->language : LANGUAGE_NONE;

  if ($node->type == 'page' && isset($node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'])) {
    // Add new template variable called $page_theme_image
    $variables['page_theme_image'] = theme('image_style', 
            array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 
                  'style_name' => 'page_theme'));
  }

}
```

and then in your tpl.php file, you just go:

```
if (!empty($page_theme_image)) {
  print $page_theme_image;
}
```